# How to add a custom mask in JQGrid columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I add a custom mask in a JQGrid column? I followed the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs), but it doesn't work.

Below my code:

```
this.montarGRID = function (p_gridName, p_dados, p_header, p_descriptor, p_contentName, p_primaryKey, p_filtroGrid) {
jQuery("#" + p_gridName).jqGrid( {
    data : p_dados, 
    datatype : "local", 
    sortable : true, 
    colNames : p_header, 
    colModel : p_descriptor, 
    rowNum : 30, 
    rowList : [30, 50, 100], 
    pager : '#p' + p_gridName, 
    recordpos : 'right', 
    viewrecords : true, 
    sortorder : "desc", 
    width: screen.availWidth - (screen.availWidth * 3 / 100),
    height : screen.availHeight - 250, 
    ignoreCase : true, 
    multiselect : false, 
    shrinkToFit : false, ...


function telefone(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
    console.log("gri.locale-pt-br.js formatter telefone " + cellValue);
    return "Telefone: " + cellValue;
}
```

My colModel value...

```
[
{formatter=integer, index=id, hidden=true, sortable=true, sorttype=integer, width=75, align=center, name=id}, 
{formatter=integer, index=VPD_GEMPI, search=false, hidden=true, sorttype=integer, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=VPD_GEMPI, editrules={number=true, required=true}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=date, formatoptions={srcformat=ISO8601Short, newformat=d/m/Y}, index=DT_DIGIT, search=true, hidden=false, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=DT_DIGIT, dateFormat=d/m/Y, editrules={required=true, date=true}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=email, index=EMAIL, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=EMAIL, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=telefone, index=TELCONTATO01, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=TELCONTATO01, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) { return telefone(cellValue, opts, rowObject); }, index=TELCONTATO02, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=TELCONTATO02, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true} 
]
```

Only integer, date, email masks work.

[image]

When my colModel formatter property is integer, currency, email, etc. it works, but when is telefone it doesn't.

Below my template formatter

```
;(function ($) {
    $.extend($.jgrid, {
        formatter :  {
        integer :  {
            thousandsSeparator : " ", 
            defaultValue : '0'
        },
        number :  {
            decimalSeparator : ",", 
            thousandsSeparator : ".", 
            decimalPlaces : 2, 
            defaultValue : '0,00'
        },
        currency :  {
            decimalSeparator : ",", 
            thousandsSeparator : ".", 
            decimalPlaces : 2, 
            prefix : "R$ ", 
            suffix : "", 
            defaultValue : '0,00'
        } ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Please publish your colModel array. This is the important part here. I suggest you to read [this link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).

Comment: I use jquery 1.11.3 version. I followed your link, but it doesn't work, it doesn't do anything. My colModel array is above, in the main message.

Comment: The question is:  Which version of jqGrid is used? (not which version of jquery)

Comment: My jqGrid version is 4.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your picture in colModel your formatter telefone will never work. 
As described in the documentation from the link that I posted, the custom formatter should be not enclosed in quotes, but just write it.

> You can define your own formatter for a particular column. Usually
>   this is a function. When set in the formatter option this should not
>   be enclosed in quotes and not entered with () - show just the name of
>   the function.

You have

```
colModel:[
    ....
    {....., foramatter : "telefone",....    }
    ....
 ]
```

This is wrong: It should be:

```
colModel:[
    ....
    {....., foramatter : telefone,....    }
    ....
 ]
```

This is a big difference

**UPDATE** : If your system can generate only strings, you can easy solve the problem extending the formatter, so that you can put string in formatter property. To solve this you can "register" your custom formatter and unformatter. For example if you want to register formatter: "telefone" you need to define $.fn.fmatter.telefone as formatter function and eventually $.fn.fmatter.telefone.unformat as unformatter function like this:

```
$.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
    telefone: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) { 
        // your code here
        ...
        // return a string 
    }
});
$.extend($.fn.fmatter.telefone, {
    unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
        // code for unformatter
        ...
    }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I generate the colModel dynamically through an array of objects. Is there any way that the formatter can be executed passing its value as a string, similar to what happens with standard formatters? Maybe some new version of jqGrid?

Comment: @GustavodeFreitas I have updated my answer in order to solve your problem.

Comment: The mask worked!!! What I need now is to put this mask on when I edit the line, in the example of the 'telefone' mask I can't type more than 11 digits or put letters. Would you help me? With "unformat" I can't do what I need

Comment: Which editing module is used? - form editing, inline editing or cell editing?